# Dividing SQL query causing an error msg

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating two separate queries and then trying to divide area_land (first query) by area_water (second query), and print the result.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('factbook.db')
total_land = conn.execute('select sum(area_land) from facts;').fetchall()
total_water = conn.execute('select sum(area_water) from facts;').fetchall()
print(total_land/total_water)
```

and this is the error I get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'

I can't figure out where my mistake is

Please help

Comment: Try printing `total_land` and `total_water` to see what they are. These appear to be lists, not integers.

Answer (score 1):

[`.fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects) returns a list of [rows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects).

You can reference the value in the returned list:

```
total_land = conn.execute('select sum(area_land) from facts;').fetchall()[0][0]
total_water = conn.execute('select sum(area_water) from facts;').fetchall()[0][0]
```

You can also use [`.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone), which returns only the first matching row:

```
total_land = conn.execute('select sum(area_land) from facts;').fetchone()[0]
total_water = conn.execute('select sum(area_water) from facts;').fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer after some more research I've come to this

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('factbook.db')
total = conn.execute('select sum(area_land) / sum(area_water) from facts where (area_land != "") & (area_water != "");').fetchall()
print(total)
```

thank you for all the reference and explanation you gave me guys (y)